# Performance impact of full length VARBINARY declarations in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to use VARBINARY column in various Snowflake tables. The corresponding data size may vary across different tables. Will there be any performance impact if I just define all such columns to be of full length?

The [offical docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#varchar) says that there is no performance impact of full length VARCHAR columns. Also, a column consumes storage for only the amount of *actual data stored*.
I am assuming that these statements are true for VARBINARY as well but couldn't find this mentioned concretely anywhere. Can somebody confirm the behaviour?

Comment: This is true for all data types.  Snowflake does not reserve space for the length of the data type, so no storage or performance impact based on the column definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mike notes it is true. I will also say it's true because the micro partition is immutable, thus if you have 1MB, 3MB, or 9MB of variant/varchar/varbinary. The data of the micro partition is written in one go in Columnar form. Thus the super variable column/s of var* data are written in one stripe.

Variable-sized data kills the performance of classic row-based DBs as the ability to seek to the next row when the row widths are not known, and thus either the use of fixed-sized columns or secondary tables to handle the dynamic blob allocation.

So back to your question if you just use type `text` for a `varchar` and look at the DDL for the table it will say something like `varchar(16777216)`, because the width is not an impactful character. from a performance perspective.

Now there is a performance impact to have huge blobs in your table, if you are reading/filtering on those columns, as all the data has to be read from the storage layer. thus if you do a `SELECT * FROM table WHERE split(massive_col,',',3) = 'eee'`
That will load huge amounts of data to find the wanted rows.

This can be improved by storing the data in the "raw" form and how you plan to break it up, if you know so you can have smaller parts that can be individually read (which is what auto-magically happens for variant data). But really if you are wanting performant processing of super-wide data, then, having it sorted by some nicely ranged clustering keys, is the best option. So when you ask for `SELECT key, suerp_massive FROM table WHERE key = 10` you prune lots of tables where there are no `10` values, thus never read the supermassive column.